# Why my custom types for this untyped import are not picked up (tiny-slider)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to use [tiny-slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider) in my TypeScript project. In my `tsconfig.json` I've set `"noImplicitAny": true,`. This JavaScript module doesn't have any typings so I get the following error:

```
node_modules/tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.module.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/tiny-slider` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'tiny-slider';`
```

... when I import tiny-slider:

```
import {tns} from 'tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.module.js';
```

What I usually do in this case I write some typings. So I added a new folder `types` and set it as `typeRoots` in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "types"
],
```

In the `types` folder I created a new file called `tiny-slider.d.ts` with the content:

```
declare module 'tiny-slider.module.js';
declare module 'tiny-slider.module';
declare module 'tiny-slider';
```

Unfortunately I still get the same error. Why my module declaration is not picked up?

Thank you for any advises!

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't the `declare`d module be the same as the one you `import ... from`, i.e. `declare module 'tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.module.js' { ... }`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thank you! You are right. Just followed the error message, which is somewhat misleading :(